# Смена содержимого php

Tags: php, ajax

Что то я совсем завис и не как не могу понять разобраться в элементарном.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Есть два файла пускай это будет index.php и test.php

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="testDiv">
  <div class='testBtm'>Click</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.testBtm', function() {
  $.post('test.php')
  .done(function( data ) {
    $('.testDiv').html(data);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
Это файл test.php
```

когда я нажимаю на Click то вывод меняется на тот что находится в файле test.php но если после изменения вывода просмотреть исходный код то исходный код будет ровно таким же как будто я только что открыл страницу index.php

Вопрос как делать полную замену что в выводе что в исходном коде?

Comment: В инструментах разработчика же видно всё, что и как меняется.

Comment: `как делать полную замену что в выводе что в исходном коде?` -- в смысле менять код исходного файла с дальнейшим сохранением что ли?

Comment: *"но если после изменения вывода просмотреть исходный код то исходный код будет ровно таким же как будто я только что открыл страницу index.php"*  --- такого быть не может

Comment: у меня такая ситуация есть две формы и они меняются между собой по нажатием кнопки при помощи ajax. При смене формы в консоль мне пишется сообщение (сделал для себя временно) так вот первое нажатие на кнопку мне пишет ... форма один успешно сменилось на вторую ... второй раз нажимаю на смену панели мне два раза выводит сообщение первое сообщение о том что форма один на вторую сменилось и следом что вторая сменилась на первую и это не смотря на то что обе формы находятся в разных файлах

Comment: @АлексейШиманский прежде чем это писать я проверил и не один раз

Comment: *"просмотреть исходный код "* --- что тут подразумевается под исходным кодом? Непосредственно если смотреть в файле или в инструментах разработчика в браузере (открыв через F12) ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский под исходным кодом я подразумеваю исходный код, а не инструмент разработчика (F12).

Comment: @Mister_X а с чего Вы взяли что он должен меняться?

Comment: @Mister_X работая с разметкой в браузере, должна меняться разветка в браузере....... логично, правда?  А код на сервере надо менять кодом на сервере

Comment: В ином случае всяк мамкин программист мог бы просто взять и из браузера поменять все исходники любого интернет магазина.... было бы не очень

Comment: `но если после изменения вывода просмотреть исходный код то исходный код будет ровно таким же как будто я только что открыл страницу index.php` эм... т.е. вам не нравится что тест вставился в индекс. `как делать полную замену что в выводе что в исходном коде?` нуууу... вместо вставки теста в индекс, просто перейти по ссылке на тест, не?

Comment: ну а если серьезно, копайте в сторону `createElement`, `appendChild`, `remuveChild`. это если говорить про vanilla js разумеется, в jQuery наверняка есть функции по изящнее.

Comment: То бишь вместо того чтобы разобраться почему на форму биндятся два события, ты решил создать какой-то пример в вакууме, который никак с твоей проблемой не связан?

Comment: @Mister_X В смысле ты нажимаешь на клик, у тебя меняется контент, но после обновления страницы у тебя пропадают изменения?

Comment: Всем кто ответил хочу сказать спасибо так или иначе помогли разобраться не много так как программирую не так часто и какие то моменты даже элементарные забываются. Разобрался в своей проблеме и оказалось что нужно было заменить строку $(document).on('click', '.testBtm', function() { на $('.testBtm').on('click', function() { и всё отрабатывает как нужно.

Comment: @SemyonBayandin я когда нажимал первый раз на клик у меня менялся контент и в консоль писалось сообщение что я сменил контент один на второй второй раз я нажимал на клик у меня опять менялся контент и в консоль у меня писалось уже два сообщения первое было что я сменил один контент на второй и второе что я сменил второй контент на первый. Как выше написал это было до тех пор пока **$(document).on('click', '.testBtm', function() {** не заменил на  **$('.testBtm').on('click', function() {**